# Creating a redirect page that handles multiple destinations?

Tags: php, redirect

I have a website with about 50 pages, each sends the visitor to a different external url, currently with a direct link to the external domain.

I'm rebuilding the website, and want to have the visitor pass first through an internal redirect page.

Instead of building 50 different redirect pages, how can I create one redirect page that would handle all these 50 different destinations?

I guess I can transform the links into

```
http://mydomain.com/redirect.php?destination=[1/2/3/4/.../50]
```

But how do I define (in the easiest way) on the redirect.php,
**the matching external URL for each of these destination numbers?**

preferably with some simple .txt file, like

```
1 http://external-1.com/
2 http://external-2.com/
.
.
50 http://external-50.com/
```

Note though that the external URLs would be composed of some PHP variables as well,
e.g.,

```
http://external-1.com/?id=<?php print $variable; ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_url($lineNo){
   $array = file("domain.txt");
   return preg_replace('/[0-50]+\. /', '', $array[$lineNo]); //removes numbering from result
}
```

All you need to do is

`http://mydomain.com/redirect.php?destination=<?php echo get_url(46) ?>`

This assumes that domain no. is in the same line as line no.

**EDIT:** Did a little more work for you. Now you can write the line nos. as well!

**EDIT 2**

Q) Would it work if my .txt file looks like this: '1 external-1.com/?id=' and my redirect.php have this command: ''

A) Change the function to this:

```
function get_url($lineNo){
   $array = file("domain.txt");
   $domain = preg_replace('/[0-50]+\. /', '', $array[$lineNo]); //removes numbering from result
   return $domain.'?id='.$lineNo; //appends $_GET['id'] to the found domain.
}
```

So if the searched domain is `1. http://www.domain-1.com/` then `http://www.domain-1.com/?id=$lineNo` would be returned.

Comment: does this mean I would have to manually count the line number for each domain I write down in the txt file, instead of writing the number before the domain, whether as a reference and whether in case I don't want the order to matter?

Comment: well, that's not necessarily the point, I'd rather have some more flexibility with assigning the numbers

Comment: Here, you happy now? :P However, this too assumes that domain 1 is on line 1 and domain 2 in on line 2 and so on.

Comment: thanks, though would it work if the URLs include additional PHP variables, that need to receive their values as I would define in the redirect.php file?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question.

Comment: would it work if my .txt file looks like this:

`1 http://external-1.com/?id=<?php print $var; ?>`

and my redirect.php have this command:

`<?php
$var= $_GET['id']
?>`

and the original page carries this link `redirect.php?id=link-no3-clicked`

Comment: Found a solution for you.

Comment: Why `http://mydomain.com/redirect.php?destination=<?php echo get_url(46) ?>` and not `http://mydomain.com/redirect.php?destination=46`?

Comment: Edited again, I think this was what you wanted.

Comment: I've decided I'd rather use something more flexible than only numbers, so I'll probably go with a `switch case`, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could build an array containing all your destination URLS, like:

```
$target = array(0 => "target1.com/something", 1 => "target2.com/somethingelse");
```

And just redirect

```
header('location:' .$target[$_GET['destination'])
```

I am using your example of URL `http://mydomain.com/redirect.php?destination=[1/2/3/4/.../50]`

Comment: so this would basically be in the same redirect.php file, and not in an external file, right? is it possible to have a more simple form than ("number => "target,com",) such as separate lines, or is that my best bet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to  provide a parameter to identifying which page you will be redirected. For external pages check yor host name. you need to keep mapping for each external sites in a array or in a txt file. e.g "1" => "externalsite.com1". if you want to mapped it in text file then you have to read it and need to retrieve the url by its key. Your Redirect php will looks like:

```
        if(isset($_REQUEST['destination']){

        switch ($_REQUEST['destination']) {
            case "1":
                //retrive the url corresponding the key  "1" and $redUrl= retrived url ;
                break;
            case "2":
                //retrive the url corresponding the key  "2" and $redUrl= retrived url  ;
                break;
            case "3":
                //retrive the url corresponding the key  "3" and $redUrl= retrived url  ;
                break;
        }
header("location:".$redUrl);
}
```

Comment: you need to keep mapping for each external sites in a array or in a txt file. e.g "1" => "externalsite.com1". if you want to mapped it in text file then you have to read it and need to retrieve the url by its key.

Comment: Where it says (in answer) `//redirect to destination 1;` replace that with `header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/folder/file.php');` @jayjay

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think now it makes sense to you :)

Comment: mmm.. can you explain the my host name part?

Comment: @Fred-ii- is there no option to have the 'header('location:' appear only once in the code, and change just the rest of it?

Comment: when you write the `//`, it's a comment, not a code, right? so I'm sure I get where is the code part in which I either place the corresponding URLs, or the URL of the TXT file that carries the corresponding URLs. I'm not a programmer but I think this part is missing...

Comment: No, that would defeat the purpose. @jayjay Having the header right now set inside `if(isset($_REQUEST['destination']){` will only redirect, it's not correct the way it is now and won't work even with the `case`s --- Look at how the braces are setup `{}`

Comment: @jayjay ,yes you are right.In comment section: you need to get corresponding url and assign in  to a variable $redUrl.

Comment: @AwladLiton - I've created a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776636/multiple-redirect-page-that-would-display-a-message-before-is-this-the-best-met) which includes some of your suggested code, now my main problem seems to be the redirection itself, as I don't think I can use PHP for the redirection, maybe you can take a look?