# Multiple Redirect page that would display a message before, is this the best method?

Tags: php, redirect, meta

I have a website with about 50 pages, each one have a text link and a banner link,
I want them to lead to the same redirect page, that would redirect them to an external URL,
according to two variables that would be in these banner/text link.

a banner link would be something like:

```
http://mydomain.com/redirect.php?dest=2&source=banner
```

Here's a code that seems to be working, I'm not a programmer so I've just compiled patches from here and there.

```
<!doctype html>
<?php

$id = $_GET['source']; // user would get to this page with an "id" that would be according to the link he clicked, either text or banner; this "id" info needs to be passed on to the external page as well, with the following "?referal" tag.

if(isset($_GET['dest'])); // user would get to this page from one of about 50 different pages; his redirect destination would depened on the "dest" number of the link he clicked

switch ($_GET['dest']) {

    case "1":
        $url = "http://url1.com/?referal=$id";
        break;

    case "2":
        $url = "http://url2.com/?referal=$id";
        break;

    case "3":
        $url = "http://url3.com/?referal=$id";
        break;

    default:
        $url = "http://unknown.com/?referal=$id";
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=<?php print $url; ?>">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<?php
$id = $_GET['source'];
if ($id == 'text'){
    echo 'The clicked link was a text link';
}
elseif ($id == 'banner'){
    echo 'The clicked link was a banner link';
}
else {
    echo 'The clicked link is unknown';
}
?>

<p></p>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['dest']));

switch ($_GET['dest']) {

    case "1":
        $url = "http://url1.com/?referal=$id";
        echo "You would be redirected to domain no. 1";
        break;

    case "2":
        $url = "http://url2.com/?referal=$id";
        echo "You would be redirected to domain no. 2";
        break;

    case "3":
        $url = "http://url3.com/?referal=$id";
        echo "You would be redirected to domain no. 3";
        break;

    default:
        echo "default";

}
 ?>  

 <P></P>
 <?php
 echo "The url you would be redirected to is: $url";
  ?>  

</body>
</html>
```

I want to know - Is this the optimal code for the purpose? also, Is it possible to make the redirect with PHP instead of META, even though I want the page to display some data?

Answer (score 1):

Test here: https://eval.in/83122

It should work. I have tested it:

```
  <!doctype html>
    <?php

    $id = $_GET['source']; // user would get to this page with an "id" that would be according to the link he clicked, either text or banner; this "id" info needs to be passed on to the external page as well, with the following "?referal" tag.

    if(isset($_GET['dest'])){ // user would get to this page from one of about 50 different pages; his redirect destination would depened on the "dest" number of the link he clicked

    switch ($_GET['dest']) {

        case "1":
            $url = "http://url1.com/?referal=$id";
            break;

        case "2":
            $url = "http://url2.com/?referal=$id";
            break;

        case "3":
            $url = "http://url3.com/?referal=$id";
            break;

        default:
            $url = "http://unknown.com/?referal=$id";
    }

    }

    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=<?php print $url; ?>">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>


    <?php
    $id = $_GET['source'];
    if ($id == 'text'){
        echo 'The clicked link was a text link';
    }
    elseif ($id == 'banner'){
        echo 'The clicked link was a banner link';
    }
    else {
        echo 'The clicked link is unknown';
    }
    ?>

    <p></p>

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['dest'])){

    switch ($_GET['dest']) {

        case "1":
            $url = "http://url1.com/?referal=$id";
            echo "You would be redirected to domain no. 1";
            break;

        case "2":
            $url = "http://url2.com/?referal=$id";
            echo "You would be redirected to domain no. 2";
            break;

        case "3":
            $url = "http://url3.com/?referal=$id";
            echo "You would be redirected to domain no. 3";
            break;

        default:
            echo "default";

    }

    }
    ?>

    <P></P>
    <?php
    echo "The url you would be redirected to is: $url";
     //header("location".$url); //enable it to redirect to the $url
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @jayjay did you try it? did you look at my given test link? you will see link in the Program Output.

Comment: yes thanks, the question though is whether it is possible to use PHP for the redirect instead of the META refresh?

Answer (score 0):

using meta is no doubt a reliable solution... But if you want a redirect using php, try following:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

or whatever file you want to redirect to.. The benefit of using header() over META is that no one could manually edit it from their browser. ;) Hope that helps..

Comment: thanks, but where in my code should I insert your code?
a header as far as I know can only be inserted at the first line of the page, and this would prevent the rest of the code to load (e.g, all the echos)

Comment: Not necessary to put on starting.. Put it wherever (as per line) you want your page to redirect...

Comment: If you're displaying a advert over your page for a few secs.. META is a good option..

Comment: If I put it anywhere besides the first line on code, I get:
`"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"`